# Difference between MessageChannel and WebSockets?

Tags: html, websocket

I can't figure out what is difference between MessageChannel and WebSockets?

I need following requirements:

- minimize delay
- full-duplex
- minimum header data length

Are both fullfil this requirements? Which is better?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[HTML5 Web Messaging API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/) can be used to communicate between independend pieces of code loaded in the browser (specification calls them "browsing contexts"). For example, if your page contains an `<iframe>`, and you want to securely communicate between it and the outside code, you might use Web Messaging. Consider [this explanation](https://dev.opera.com/articles/window-postmessage-messagechannel/#channel) from the Opera dev portal:

> Channel messaging is particularly useful for communication across
>   multiple origins. Consider the following scenario. We have a document
>   at http://socialsite.example containing content from
>   http://games.example embedded in one iframe, and content from
>   http://addressbook.example in another.
>
> Now let’s say that we want to
>   send a message from our address book site to our games site. We could
>   use the social site as a proxy. That, however, means the address book
>   gains the same level of trust as the social site. Our social site
>   either has to trust every request, or filter them for us.
>
> With channel
>   messaging, however, http://addressbook.example and
>   http://games.example can communicate directly.

[Web Sockets API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091222/) can be used to communicate between code loaded in the browser and the server. So it serves a completely different purpose. Since you're mentioning the requirement of low latency and "full-duplex" I assume you mean client-server communication, and so you're looking for a web sockets.

Comment: The good news is that Firefox does support channel messaging (MessageChannel) since a while ago.

Comment: But isn't the Messages API a low latency and full-duplex (2-way communication) between contexts? A MS book states: "A common use of WebSockets is for an in-browser instant messaging client", but is the Messaging API more apropriate?

Comment: Messaging API is all about exchanging messages between various pieces of code running in the browser. For instance, a web worker might want to talk to the code running in the main thread. Or a website loaded in an iframe might talk to the page that loaded it. But Messaging API *__is not__* a way to communicate over the network - like WebSockets is. So you can't implement an IM client with it.

Comment: Maybe this will make it clear: WebSockets is used to send data over network, usually between a browser and a server. Messaging API is used to send data between threads / processes within a single browser.