# When to use MessageChannel HTML5 feature?

Tags: html, websocket

When we need to use messageChannel? I usually know websocket protocol used when there is need full duplex and low latency.. etc.  Also Websocket used during client server communication.  Can  I use MessageChannel instead of web-socket? My client are using chrome so less worried about other browsers.  Does it satisfy full duplex and low latency requirement?

Need to know messagechannel support low latency and full duplex feature

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between MessageChannel and WebSockets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620567/difference-between-messagechannel-and-websockets)